# Whole disk is a partition: can't shrink, can't create new one

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted

When I set up arch linux, I created a partition with fdisk, and ran `mkfs.ext4` **on `/dev/sda`**.

Now, I want to partition `/dev/sda` to have 2 partitions, instead of just one. The problem is, that when I try to resize `/dev/sda`, it shows that the unallocated space is **in** the partition, and I cannot create a new partition.

[image: image of setup in gparted]

Comment: It seems technically it's not a partition. You have a filesystem on the *entire device*.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yup, that's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a volume without a partition table to one with a partition table one can copy the data elsewhere than back again after the format, **or** perform the operation in place;

- shrink the file system to start at 1GB and end 1GB before the end.
- note down the exact start/end locations.
- write a new partition table (will look like the data is lost)
- create a partition around the noted locations.

you may want to do this on a test volume before trying it with important data so you know how to do it correctly.